# How to use JSON data with php?

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON as shown below present in a file **ptp-ess_landing.json**.

**ptp-ess_landing.json** file:

```
{"toggle_multi_tiles":["1","2","3","4"]}
```

I have another php file (**depth.php**) in which I have some css codes.

Inside the **depth.php**, I have the following php code which makes **depth.php** and **ptp-ess_landing.json** to communicate with each other.

```
if (file_exists('feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json')) {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json'));
}
```

What I want to achieve in **depth.php** file is,

**Case A**, When JSON is this `{"toggle_multi_tiles":["1","2","3","4"]}`, following CSS should be called:

```
<style>
.hello-world {
    display:block;      
}
</style>
```

**Case B**, When JSON is this `{"toggle_multi_tiles":["1","2","3"]}`, following CSS should be called:

```
<style>
.hello-world {
    display:inline-block;       
}
</style>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
<style>
<?php if($data->toggle_multi_tiles["1","2","3","4"]) { ?>   // Line A
.hello-world {
    display:block;      
}
<?php } ?>
</style>

<style>
<?php if($data->toggle_multi_tiles["1","2","3"]) { ?>      // Line B
.hello-world {
    display:inline-block;       
}
<?php } ?>
</style>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am getting error at **Line A/Line B**. I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above at **Line A/Line B** so that it goes inside the if block with particular **dataset of JSON**.

**Edit 1:**

On doing `var_dump($data);` inside `depth.php` file, I am getting the following on the webpage `["toggle_multi_tiles"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4" }`

On doing `print_r($data);` inside `depth.php` file I am getting `[toggle_multi_tiles] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )` on the webpage

Comment: Please tell us what error you're encountering. We can't really do much to help you otherwise.

Comment: It seems strange to dynamically render CSS. Does this situation get any easier if you have mutliple CSS classes (e.g. `.hello-world-block` and `.hello-world-inline`) and then change your depth.php code to put the correct class in the markup?

Comment: @B.Fleming expected semicolon at **Line A/ Line B**. Probably thats not the right way.

Comment: `$data->toggle_multi_tiles["1","2","3"]` is wrong, but its not clear what your trying to compare them 3 entries with i.e `<?php if(in_array(1, $data->toggle_multi_tiles)) { ?>` makes more sence if your toggling stuff

Comment: You're missing a semicolon in your PHP code, then. You need to terminate statements (not opening/closing blocks) with a semicolon `;` in order to tell PHP where the statement ends. Please review where PHP is telling you you're missing the semicolon and look around that line for where it's missing, then add it in place.

Comment: More information. On doing `var_dump($data);` inside depth.php file, I am getting the following on the webpage `["toggle_multi_tiles"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4" }`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use var_dump on `$data`? Is it really json? Also your `if` statements are not right. Try this. Let me know if it doesn't works. If you get error, please share it with us. They helps a lot to understand what's wrong.

```
<?php

   if (!file_exists('feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json')) {
       die('File not found');
       exit();
   }

   $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('feeds/ptp-ess_landing.json'));

   $display = (array)$data->toggle_multi_tiles == ["1", "2", "3"]
              ? 'inline-block'
              : 'block';
?>

   <style>
       .hello-world {
           display:<?php echo $display ?>;
       }
   </style>
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/hJtZs)

Demo doesn't read data from file. Instead of it, i added data manually.

Comment: careful with ordering, https://3v4l.org/a8RTH

Comment: On doing `var_dump($data);` inside depth.php file, I am getting the following on the webpage `["toggle_multi_tiles"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4" }`

Comment: thanks. It means, you can read data. And this code works if you can read it.